# date and value column split to two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data that 1-dimensional float64 data that contain date and value as like this:

```
2019-03-08 00:00:00-03:00    0.0
2019-03-08 00:01:00-03:00    0.0
2019-03-08 00:02:00-03:00    0.0
2019-03-08 00:03:00-03:00    0.0
2019-03-08 00:04:00-03:00    0.0
                            ... 
2019-03-08 23:55:00-03:00    0.0
2019-03-08 23:56:00-03:00    0.0
2019-03-08 23:57:00-03:00    0.0
2019-03-08 23:58:00-03:00    0.0
2019-03-08 23:59:00-03:00    0.0
Freq: T, Name: ABC, Length: 1440, dtype: float64
```

I want to split time and value data and put them into two columns ('Date' and 'Value') simply.

I tried the following to know:

```
df.shape
(1440,)
df.dtypes
dtype('float64')
```

Seeing it 1D data, I tried to change the format into dataframe

```
df2=df.to_frame()
df2.shape
(1440,1)
```

There, I tried "str.split" and other commands that I searched in the internet but but none of them worked. I couldn't help but "detouring" like this:

```
df2.to_csv('Test.csv')
df_interim=pd.read_csv('Test.csv')
df_interim.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 0": "Time","ABC":"Value"},inplace=True)
df_interim.set_index('Time')
df_interim.to_csv('complete.csv')
```

Of course, it works but, I'd like to do it more efficiently not creating a csv file, reading it and saving it just only to fix that issue.
What should I implement? It may be something simple but I haven't got through yet

------Edited the first time. Attached the original coding----
I am using a library as following:

```
from pvlib import solarposition, tracking
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tz = 'US/Eastern'
lat, lon = 40, -80

times = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', closed='left', freq='5min',
                      tz=tz)
solpos = solarposition.get_solarposition(times, lat, lon)

truetracking_angles = tracking.singleaxis(
    apparent_zenith=solpos['apparent_zenith'],
    apparent_azimuth=solpos['azimuth'],
    axis_tilt=0,
    axis_azimuth=180,
    max_angle=90,
    backtrack=False,  # for true-tracking
    gcr=0.5)  # irrelevant for true-tracking

truetracking_position = truetracking_angles['tracker_theta'].fillna(0)
```

When Iput,

```
truetracking_position
```

I see

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00-05:00    0.0
2019-01-01 00:05:00-05:00    0.0
2019-01-01 00:10:00-05:00    0.0
2019-01-01 00:15:00-05:00    0.0
2019-01-01 00:20:00-05:00    0.0
                            ... 
2019-01-01 23:35:00-05:00    0.0
2019-01-01 23:40:00-05:00    0.0
2019-01-01 23:45:00-05:00    0.0
2019-01-01 23:50:00-05:00    0.0
2019-01-01 23:55:00-05:00    0.0
Freq: 5T, Name: tracker_theta, Length: 288, dtype: float64
```

It gives a weird (1440,0) shape of string..

Comment: How did you end up in a 1-dimensional float64 data in pandas itself though? It should take it as a string or something. I don't understand. May be the 2nd column will be taken as float. I think the data you provided here is from some other program like numpy or something which treating it as a vector of length 1440. Because it's hard to recreate the data input which is provided here. So, can't test with the given dataframe . Reading from csv part is ok though.

Comment: Hello, Tanmaya I attached the original coding for you to understand better

Comment: You don't need to split the data and save into a  file and then read a  file to use the data here. Unless you want it to save to csv and done for the program or project, you can literally do so many things with it. the dataframe `truetracking_position` is like a magical dictionary. I have edited the answer take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change anything in this dataframe called `truetracking_position`. Reason is the datetime are taken as rows for easy access of `values`. I installed the module `pvlib` and ran the same program. It's not a vector of string but a dataframe of floa64 datatype.

Unless you want it to save into csv using 2 columns as data, it's actually not a good idea to split it. why? take a look at below what it can do for you.

```
In [58]: truetracking_position['2019-01-01 12:30:00-05:00']
Out[58]: 3.2641041244419426

In [60]: truetracking_position['2019-01-01 12']
Out[60]: 
2019-01-01 12:00:00-05:00   -11.814614
2019-01-01 12:05:00-05:00    -9.333005
2019-01-01 12:10:00-05:00    -6.831898
2019-01-01 12:15:00-05:00    -4.316320
2019-01-01 12:20:00-05:00    -1.791519
2019-01-01 12:25:00-05:00     0.737108
2019-01-01 12:30:00-05:00     3.264104
2019-01-01 12:35:00-05:00     5.784038
2019-01-01 12:40:00-05:00     8.291590
2019-01-01 12:45:00-05:00    10.781636
2019-01-01 12:50:00-05:00    13.249319
2019-01-01 12:55:00-05:00    15.690115
Freq: 5T, Name: tracker_theta, dtype: float64

In [73]: truetracking_position[truetracking_position!=0]
Out[73]: 
2019-01-01 07:45:00-05:00   -89.752336
2019-01-01 07:50:00-05:00   -88.923132
2019-01-01 07:55:00-05:00   -88.049750
2019-01-01 08:00:00-05:00   -87.140644
2019-01-01 08:05:00-05:00   -86.203868
                               ...    
2019-01-01 16:40:00-05:00    85.782406
2019-01-01 16:45:00-05:00    86.729102
2019-01-01 16:50:00-05:00    87.650821
2019-01-01 16:55:00-05:00    88.540767
2019-01-01 17:00:00-05:00    89.389841
Freq: 5T, Name: tracker_theta, Length: 112, dtype: float64
```

In the above code line you can simply access data using time, timeframes, a particular day or exact time too. so, basically the datetime here is acting as a `key` in a dictionary which is  good. Plus, you can further process the data. For example, in the above code lines, i have tried accessing 3 things. first one is at a particular datetime what is the value. Then secondly, i tried accessing basically an hour of data from 12 to 12:55. Third, i tried which values of the dataframe `truetracking_position` is non-zero and look at those beautiful outputs.

Even you can plot data directly from here. Take a look below for a little change in your code.

```
from pvlib import solarposition, tracking
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tz = 'US/Eastern'
lat, lon = 40, -80

times = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', closed='left', freq='5min',
                      tz=tz)
solpos = solarposition.get_solarposition(times, lat, lon)

truetracking_angles = tracking.singleaxis(
    apparent_zenith=solpos['apparent_zenith'],
    apparent_azimuth=solpos['azimuth'],
    axis_tilt=0,
    axis_azimuth=180,
    max_angle=90,
    backtrack=False,  # for true-tracking
    gcr=0.5)  # irrelevant for true-tracking

truetracking_position = truetracking_angles['tracker_theta'].fillna(0)
ttp = pd.DataFrame({'Time':truetracking_position.index, 'Value':truetracking_position.values}) # Convert to dataframe with the datetime as a column
ttp.to_csv("ttp_data.csv") # save to csv
ttp_non_zero = truetracking_position[truetracking_position!=0] # Extract non-zero Values

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # Add 2 subplots in one pic.
ttp_non_zero.plot(color='red',linewidth=4,linestyle='dashed') # Plot the non-zero data directly.
truetracking_position.plot(color='green',linewidth=2) # Plot all data directly.
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: Tracking Position Data Plotted]

That being said, unless you just want it to save into a csv and you have reached the end of your entire program/project and don't want to further use this data, i won't suggest splitting. Use the data as it is like a dictionary look up with many extra features.

**Edit:** Code edited for saving data into csv file as per the question and can be used in a visualization software.

Comment: Hello, Tanmaya sorry for confusion that I made. I attached the original coding. Since it is an outcome of a library, I cannot even set such "header" nor access to the df as normally I can do..

Comment: Hello, Tanmaya
Thanks for all clear explanation. I actually intended to save the dataset into csv file to do further work in visual software. That's why I didn't want to use it as "dictionary" tool.
Seeing the saving part that you suggested, eventually I should make a 'Test.csv' file to save to do what I wanted, right?

Comment: @blackbeaans If you are upto working in a visualization software then you just need one line of code after that `truetrackingposition` variable . `ttp = pd.DataFrame({'Time':truetracking_position.index, 'Value':truetracking_position.values})` . Then save `ttp` to csv file. Edited the code. Take a look.